# How to implement "user interactive" dependency injection in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I have a full engine that relies on abstractions based on user interactions. This works great with WPF/Xamarin app, cause I can implements this abstractions with window/form.

I have a little problem for porting this engine into ASP MVC.

A simple example can be show as this.

Abstraction interface (simplified)

```
public interface IQuestionBox
{
    Task<bool> ShowYesNoQuestionBox(string message);
}
```

For WPF, it's really simple, I implement this interface as return the result of a window by calling ShowDialog().

In a simple business class, I can have this kind of calls (simplified) :

```
public async Task<string> GetValue(IQuestionBox qbox)
{
    if(await qbox.ShowYesNoQuestionBox("Question ?"))
    {
        return "Ok";
    }
    return "NOk";
}
```

I really don't see how can I implement this kind of behavior in ASP, due to stateless of HTTP, knowing that this kind of call can be as various as domain/business need. The way I think it should be done is by returning a PartialView to inject into popup, but I don't see how to do this without breaking all the process ...

Anyone has ever done this ?

Comment: If you have persistent connection with user via websockets or similar, send message to user via that  channel, in javascript read it and show user dialog (in JS, no server involved), then send message back to server with user's decision. Not sure how practical it is, but allows to match your interface.

Comment: What process are you breaking doing that?

Comment: My business process needs to know the answer to this question to choose  from one code path to another. Because it's strictly business concerns, I cannot break my code in two blocks, it would break the business logic.
Also, WebSocket could be a solution, because in my C#, I cannot wait for a HttpResponse... it worth a try

Comment: I've just added another answer below.

Comment: You can certainly do this with SignalR - send a message to the client javascript and return a task that will wait for the users response, the user performs an action which triggers a request, which triggers the completion of the task and the method continues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a web socket connection from client side to server side. And work with front-end content with web socket request. It could be implemented as following:

Client side:

```
$app = {
    uiEventsSocket : null,
    initUIEventsConnection : function(url) {
        //create a web socket connection
        if (typeof (WebSocket) !== 'undefined') {
                this.uiEventsSocket = new WebSocket(url);
            } else if (typeof (MozWebSocket) !== 'undefined') {
                this.uiEventsSocket = new MozWebSocket(url);
            } else {
                console.error('WebSockets unavailable.');
            }

            //notify if there is an web socket error
            this.uiEventsSocket.onerror = function () {
                console.error('WebSocket raised error.');
            }

            this.uiEventsSocket.onopen = function () {
                console.log("Connection to " + url + " established");
            }

            //handling message from server side
            this.uiEventsSocket.onmessage = function (msg) {
                this._handleMessage(msg.data);
            };
    },

    _handleMessage : function(data){
        //the message should be in json format
        //the next line fails if it is not
        var command = JSON.parse(data);

        //here is handling the request to show prompt
        if (command.CommandType == 'yesNo') {
            var message = command.Message;

            var result = confirm(message);
            //not sure that bool value will be successfully converted
            this.uiEventsSocket.send(result ? "true" : "false");
        }
    }
}
```

And init it from `ready` or `load` event:

```
window.onload = function() { $app.initUIEventsConnection(yourUrl); }
```

Note that you url should begin with `ws://` instead of `http://` and `wss://` instead of `https://` (Web Sockets and Web Sockets Secure).

Server side.

[Here](https://radu-matei.github.io/blog/aspnet-core-websockets-middleware/) is a good article for how to setup web sockets at asp.net core application or you could find another one. Note that you should group web socket connections from single user and if you want to send a message to the concrete user, you should send message for every connection from this user.

Every web socket you should accept with `AcceptWebSocketAsync()` method call and then add instance of this web socket to singleton, which contains a set of web sockets connection groupped by user.

The following class will be used to operate commands:

```
public class UICommand
{
    public string CommandType { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Type ReturnType { get; set; }
}
```

And a full code of singleton for handling sockets

```
public class WebSocketsSingleton
{
    private static WebSocketsSingleton _instance = null;
    //here stored web sockets groupped by user
    //you could use user Id or another marker to exactly determine the user
    private Dictionary<string, List<WebSocket>> _connectedSockets;

    //for a thread-safety usage
    private static readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim Locker = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public static WebSocketsSingleton Instance {
        get {
            if (this._instance == null)
            {
                this._instance = new WebSocketsSingleton();
            }

            return this._instance;
        }
    }

    private WebSocketsSingleton()
    {
        this._connectedSockets = new Dictionary<string, List<WebSocket>>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a socket into the required collection
    /// </summary>
    public void AddSocket(string userName, WebSocket ws)
    {
        if (!this._connectedSockets.ContainsKey(userName))
        {
            Locker.EnterWriteLock();
            try
            {
                this._connectedSockets.Add(userName, new List<WebSocket>());
            }
            finally
            {
                Locker.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }

        Locker.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            this._connectedSockets[userName].Add(ws);
        }
        finally
        {
            Locker.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends a UI command to required user
    /// </summary>  
    public async Task<string> SendAsync(string userName, UICommand command)
    {
        if (this._connectedSockets.ContainsKey(userName))
        {
            var sendData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(command));

        foreach(var item in this._connectedSockets[userName])
        {
            try
            {
                await item.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(sendData), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                //socket removed from front end side
            }
        }

            var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
            var token = CancellationToken.None;         
            foreach(var item in this._connectedSockets[userName])
            {
                await Task.Run(async () => {
                    var tempResult = await item.ReceiveAsync(buffer, token);
                    //result received
                    token = new CancellationToken(true);
                });
            }

            var resultStr = Encoding.Utf8.GetString(buffer.Array);

            if (command.ReturnType == typeof(bool))
            {
                return resultStr.ToLower() == "true";
            }

            //other methods to convert result into required type

            return resultStr;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Explanation:

- on establishing connection from web socket it will be added with
  `AddSocket` method
- on sending request to show a message, the required command will be passed into `SendAsync` method
- the command will be serialized to JSON (using Json.Net, however you could serialize in your way) and send to all sockets, related to the required user
- after the command sent, application will wait for respond from front end side
- the result will be converted to required type and sent back to your `IQuestionBox`

In the web socket handling your should add some kind of the following code:

```
app.Use(async (http, next) =>
{
    if (http.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        var webSocket = await http.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
        var userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        WebSocketsSingleton.Instance.AddSocket(userName, webSocket);

        while(webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            //waiting till it is not closed         
        }

        //removing this web socket from the collection
    }
});
```

And your method implementation of `ShowYesNoQuestionBox` should be kind of following:

```
public async Task<bool> ShowYesNoQuestionBox(string userName, string text)
{
    var command = new UICommand
    {
        CommandType = "yesNo",
        Message = text,
        ReturnType = typeof(bool)
    };

    return await WebSocketsSingleton.Instance.SendAsync(string userName, command);
}
```

Note that there should be added `userName` to prevent sending the same message to all of the connected users.

`WebSocket` should create the persistent connection between server and client sides, so you could simply send commands in two ways.

I am kindly new to Asp.Net Core, so the final implementation could be a bit different from this.

Comment: WebSocket seems definitly the way to go, thanks for explaination

Answer (score 2):

as I've said, I strongly doesn't recommend this pratice, but its possible, bellow the code that allows to do it, let's go:

To become it's possible I abused the use from [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx), this class allow us to set manually result in a task.

- First we need to create a structure to encapsulate the process:

  ```
  public class Process
  {
       // this dictionary store the current process running status, you will use it to define the future answer from the user interaction
       private static Dictionary<string, Answare> StatusReport = new Dictionary<string, Answare>();
       // this property is the secret to allow us wait for the ShowYesNoQuestion call, because til this happen the server doesn't send a response for the client.
       TaskCompletionSource<bool> AwaitableResult { get; } = new      TaskCompletionSource<bool>(true);
       // here we have the question to interact with the user
       IQuestionBox QuestionBox { get; set; }

       // this method, receive your bussiness logical the receive your question as a parameter
       public IQuestionBox Run(Action<IQuestionBox> action)
       {
           QuestionBox = new QuestionBox(this);
           // here we create a task to execute your bussiness logical processment
           Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
           {
              action(QuestionBox);
           });
           // and as I said we wait the result from the processment
           Task.WaitAll(AwaitableResult.Task);
           // and return the question box to show the messages for the users
           return QuestionBox;
       }

       // this method is responsable to register a question to receive future answers, as you can see, we are using our static dictionary to register them
       public void RegisterForAnsware(string id)
       {
          if (StatusReport.ContainsKey(id))
             return;
          StatusReport.Add(id, new Answare()
          {
          });
       }

       // this method will deliver an answer for this correct context based on the id
       public Answare GetAnsware(string id)
       {
           if (!StatusReport.ContainsKey(id))
             return Answare.Empty;
           return StatusReport[id];
       }

       // this method Releases the processment
       public void Release()
       {
           AwaitableResult.SetResult(true);
       }

       // this method end the process delivering the response for the user
       public void End(object userResponse)
       {
          if (!StatusReport.ContainsKey(QuestionBox.Id))
             return;
          StatusReport[QuestionBox.Id].UserResponse(userResponse);
       }

       // this method define the answer based on the user interaction, that allows the process continuing from where it left off
       public static Task<object> DefineAnsware(string id, bool result)
       {
           if (!StatusReport.ContainsKey(id))
             return Task.FromResult((object)"Success on the operation");
           // here I create a taskcompletaionsource to allow get the result of the process, and send for the user, without it would be impossible to do it
           TaskCompletionSource<object> completedTask = new           TaskCompletionSource<object>();
           StatusReport[id] = new Answare(completedTask)
           {
              HasAnswared = true,
              Value = result
           };
           return completedTask.Task;
       }
  }
  ```
- After that the question implementation

  ```
  public interface IQuestionBox
  {
      string Id { get; }
      Task<bool> ShowYesNoQuestionBox(string question);
      HtmlString ShowMessage();
  }

  class QuestionBox : IQuestionBox
  {
      Process CurrentProcess { get; set; }

      public string Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
      private string Question { get; set; }

      public QuestionBox(Process currentProcess)
      {
          CurrentProcess = currentProcess;
          CurrentProcess.RegisterForAnswer(this.Id);
      }

      public Task<bool> ShowYesNoQuestionBox(string question)
      {
          Question = question;
          CurrentProcess.Release();
          return AwaitForAnswer();
      }

      public HtmlString ShowMessage()
      {
          HtmlString htm = new HtmlString(
              $"<script>showMessage('{Question}', '{Id}');</script>"
          );

          return htm;
      }

      private Task<bool> AwaitForAnswer()
      {
          TaskCompletionSource<bool> awaitableResult = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(true);

          Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
          {
              while (true)
              {
                  Thread.Sleep(2000);
                  var answare = CurrentProcess.GetAnswer(this.Id);
                  if (!answare.HasAnswered)
                      continue;
                  awaitableResult.SetResult(answare.Value);
                  break;
              }
          });

          return awaitableResult.Task;
      }
  }
  ```

The differences for yours implementaion are:

1 - I create an Identifier to know for who I have to send the aswer, or just to stop the process.

2 - I receive a Process as parameter, because this allows us to call the method 
CurrentProcess.Release(); in ShowYesNoQuestion, here in specific, releases the process to send the response responsable to interact with the user.

3 - I create the method AwaitForAnswer, here one more time we use from the TaskCompletionSource class. As you can see in this method we have a loop, this loop is responsable to wait for the user interaction, and til receive a response it doesn't release the process.

4 - I create the method ShowMessage that create a simple html script alert to simulate the user interaction.

- Then a simple process class as you should be in your bussiness logical:

  ```
  public class SaleService
  {
     public async Task<string> GetValue(IQuestionBox qbox)
     {
        if (await qbox.ShowYesNoQuestionBox("Do you think Edney is the big guy ?"))
        {
             return "I knew, Edney is the big guy";
        }
        return "No I disagree";
     }
  }
  ```
- And then the class to represent the user answer

  ```
  public class Answer
  {
      // just a sugar to represent empty responses
      public static Answer Empty { get; } = new Answer { Value = true, HasAnswered = true };

      public Answer()
      {

      }

      // one more time abusing from TaskCompletionSource<object>, because with this guy we are abble to send the result from the process to the user
      public Answer(TaskCompletionSource<object> completedTask)
      {
          CompletedTask = completedTask;
      }

      private TaskCompletionSource<object> CompletedTask { get; set; }

      public bool Value { get; set; }
      public bool HasAnswered { get; set; }

      // this method as you can see, will set the result and release the task for the user
      public void UserResponse(object response)
      {
          CompletedTask.SetResult(response);
      }
  }
  ```
- Now we use all the entire structure create for this:

  ```
  [HttpPost]
  public IActionResult Index(string parametro)
  {
      // create your process an run it, passing what you want to do
      Process process = new Process();
      var question = process.Run(async (questionBox) =>
      {
          // we start the service
          SaleService service = new SaleService();
          // wait for the result
          var result = await service.GetValue(questionBox);
          // and close the process with the result from the process
          process.End(result);
      });

      return View(question);
  }

  // here we have the method that deliver us the user response interaction
  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<JsonResult> Answer(bool result, string id)
  {
      // we define the result for an Id on the process
      var response = await Process.DefineAnswer(id, result);
      // get the response from process.End used bellow
      // and return to the user
      return Json(response);
  }
  ```
- and in your view

  ```
   <!-- Use the question as the model  page -->
   @model InjetandoInteracaoComUsuario.Controllers.IQuestionBox
   <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
       <!-- create a simple form with a simple button to submit the home -->
       <input type="submit" name="btnDoSomething" value="All about Edney" />
   </form>
   <!-- in the scripts section we create the function that we call on the method ShowMessage, remember?-->
   <!-- this method request the action answer passing the questionbox id, and the result from a simple confirm -->
   <!-- And to finalize, it just show an  alert with the process result -->
   @section scripts{
   <script>
        function showMessage(message, id) {
           var confirm = window.confirm(message);
           $.post("/Home/Answer", { result: confirm, id: id }, function (e) {
              alert(e);
           })
        }

   </script>
   @Model?.ShowMessage()
  }
  ```

As I've said, I realy disagree with this pratices, the correct should to write a new dll, to support the web enviroment, but I hope it help you.

I put the project on github to you can **[download](https://github.com/EdneySilva/InjetandoInteracaoComUsuario)** an understand all the solution

I realy hope it can help you

Comment: Creating the dialogbox is not really the issue, my issue is to stop the process until the user answer to the question (in this case). Other type of interruption could be a selection into a list, a multiple options choice, ...

Comment: In this case I would recomend you use SignalR, that allows you mantain a open channel with your server, and if something happened that needs to interrupt the process, you just send a message to the server requesting the process interrupt. [Here](https://www.asp.net/signalr) there are a lot things about how use it.

Comment: @cdie A question before post a different solution for your problem. When the user interaction interrupt the process, you need some response from the server, or just needs to interrupt that and nothing more?

Comment: there is no really process interruption, more process pausing. In fact, the answer will modify some properties that will change all the engine behavior. Even if user doesn't pick an item within a list, it will not stop the execution, only take a different path of code

Comment: @cdie and the server trigger this "question" right?

Comment: kind of, the code on server have to wait for the user interaction. The server have to send a message to client to ask for a particular user interaction, and wait for the answer before processing

Comment: @cdie now I got it, and the last question, which asp.net version are you using?

Comment: ASP MVC Core 1.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137366/discussion-between-edney-batista-da-silva-and-cdie).

Answer (score 0):

It's actually much the same, except your UI is sort of disconnected and proxied with the HTTP protocol for the most part.

you essentially need to build the same code as your WPF code but then in the browser construct ajax calls in to the controller actions to apply your logic.

To clarify ...

so lets say you are building up a process over a series of questions that based on the users answer you put different steps in to the process.

You can either ...

1. build the process in the database
2. build it in session on the server
3. build it on the client as a js object

then do a post for execution ofthe constructed process.

think of the "statelessness" as a series of short interactions, but the state you keep between them can be done either on the client, in a db or in the users logged in session on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can add an ActionResult that will give you the html response to your jquery modal popup request. Here is an example

```
public class MController : Controller {
            public ActionResult doWork(requirement IQuestionBox)
            { 
                // model is already modelBound/IOC resolved
                return PartialView("_doWork", requirement );
            }    
        }
```

//scripts

```
$(function(){    
        $.ajax({
           url:"/m/doWork",
           type:"get",
           success:function(data){
               $modal.html(data); // bind to modal
           }
        });
});
```

Apologies for not fully understanding the question.

hope this helps!

Comment: The Inversion Of Control IS NOT my question, please read carefuly

Comment: How do you resolve IQuestionBox? To do so in MVC you use a dependency resolver. Is this what you are trying to achieve? Otherwise  you are searching for the anti-pattern service locator. I hope this helps.

Comment: The question is not about resolving, I know how to do. The question is how can I implement this abstraction in ASP MVC to make it synchronous with user interactions

Comment: Oh! Are you asking about using jquery modal popup?